# Why Facebook debugger raise: The crawler accepts deflate and gzip content encodings

Tags: animation, facebook-opengraph, content-encoding

Got this warning: `Image Unavailable`

```
Provided og:image, https://t44-post-cover.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/7ou5 could not be downloaded. This can happen due to several different reasons such as your server using unsupported content-encoding. The crawler accepts deflate and gzip content encodings.
```

If I send a `GET` to `https://t44-post-cover.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/7ou5` and pass `Accept-Encoding`: `gzip` and `Content-Encoding`: `gzip` in Postman, I got back the gif, what is then the problem?

Content is less than 8MB, it is 6.23 MB.

[image]

Got this error calling crawler from Graph API:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid parameter",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 1611071,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "URL Follow Failed",
    "error_user_msg": "There was an error in fetching the object at URL 'https://tikex-dev.com/kubl/38fn/j1vd/2mi1', or one of the URLs specified via a redirect or the 'og:url' property including one of https://t44-post-cover.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/7ou5.",
    "fbtrace_id": "A4YG8eB4cFHG9acjUaDuCKk"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is happening because you are not linking it to a direct file download link with og:image.

Comment: You can see it is and `image/gif`. What you mean "linking it to a direct file download link"?

Comment: @János i have edited my response to be more clear.