# How Giphy share differently gif animation on Facebook than my site?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, gif, meta-tags

Comparing this Giphy sharing page: https://giphy.com/clips/studiosoriginals-bastille-day-14-juillet-happy-LEIGgMyBl6AdW28Auh

with my page https://tikex-dev.com/kubl/38fn/j1vd/2mi1

When pressing share on Facebook, both should have the same result: able see an Facebook an animating image, but it happens only for Giphy sharing page.

- Fact 1: Both page has an `og:image` which is different from the url or `og:url` itself.

Giphy:

```
https://media4.giphy.com/media/LEIGgMyBl6AdW28Auh/giphy.gif?cid=790b76117edbcc7a9a196c63853f26dcf0b86d9d9a093789&rid=giphy.gif&ct=v
```

my:

```
https://t44-post-cover.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/7ou5
```

- Fact 2: Both `og:url` point to the loaded url itself.
- Fact 3: If I share the gif file itself, not the sharing page, with the AWS S3 link, then animation is carry out on Facebook. So GIF content encoding is ok.
- Fact 4: Some people proposed point with `og:url` to the `og:image` link. When I set it,`og:url` was not loaded from meta tags, and based on Facebook Debugger `og:url` still was pointed to the sharing page.

Is it a problem, that the gif itself is not visible on the sharing page, only a link has in the headers?

Answer (score 0):

The tikex-dev.com page you've linked og tags point to invalid AWS endpoints.
In any case you should use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ to debug your og tags.

Edit:
Now it has changed to a valid one and showing correctly.

Comment: I see, you need to scrape it again, do you have any idea about the problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72692668/how-rs-layer-wrap-makes-the-animation

Comment: Is MIME something else then Content-Type?

Comment: no the MIME is what is contained inside Content-Type, for example image/png.

Comment: No, `image/gif` is set for `Content-Type`, look here the screen shot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72692668/why-facebook-debugger-raise-the-crawler-accepts-deflate-and-gzip-content-encodi?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Yep, i didn't notice because chrome was getting cached version of it, and that's why i edited my answer, check the other post u created for the answer.